# How to persistently change the owner of /sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-1000.slice

Tags: cgroup

On my Ubuntu 22.04 system, the cgroup `/sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-1000.slice` is owned by `root`.

How would I persistently change this so that this cgroup (and all its descendants) are instead owned by user `1000`?  By "persistently", I mean across logins and across reboots.

What manages all the cgroups on Ubuntu?  Systemd?  Something else?

Are there configuration files I can tweak that will change cgroup management (specifically in terms of cgroup ownership, and specifically for the `user.slice` cgroup and its descendants)?